# Unable to use USB port to program radio in Chirp

Tags: usb, permissions, ham-radio, chirp

The following in Terminal tends to lead me to believe that I would use ttyS4 to access a Baofeng radio in Chirp. However, when I try it, I get a "permission denied". In fact, no matter what I try, "permission denied" on all listed ports.  Help.

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[   45.596670] INT3435:00: ttyS4 at MMIO 0xfe10d000 (irq = 13, base_baud = 6250000) is a 16550A
[ 4323.580098] usb 2-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your user to the "dialout" group. Open a terminal an do:

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout username
```

Replace "username" with your Ubuntu user.

Source: [Running CHIRP under Linux](http://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Running_Under_Linux)